# VSTS MSDeploy Deep Nested Path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-devops

I am using VSTS build for publishing my ASP.Net project and I am using below MSBuild argument to create the package.

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageTempRootDir=Binaries/$(BuildConfiguration) /p:PackageLocation=$(Build.stagingDirectory)\xxxxxxx.zip
```

It's generating a package in a path shown as below

api_drop\API\Content\D_C\a\1\s\Source\xxxxx.API\ABC.PSP.OuC.TMW.Api\obj\Release\net471\PubTmp\Out

Now I want the binaries from Out directories to be zipped but MsDeploy command gives me complete above path in zip.

How can I flatten it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you get useful information from Andy's suggestion? If it is helpful for you, you could accept it as the answer, if not, feel free to share the latest information here.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to output the files without zip, then you can try below ways:

1. Specify the argument `OutputPath` only (without specifying the package
   related arguments):

e.g:

```
/p:OutputPath="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\cc"
```

You can also output the target files to a shared path (UNC path):

e.g:

```
/p:OutputPath="\\myshare\DirA\0313"
```

2. Then use **Copy and Publish build Artifacts** task to publish the
   files. Alternatively you can add a **Copy Files** task to copy the
   files from `OutputPath` to a **Temp folder**, then use **Publish
   build Artifacts** task to publish the files from **Temp folder**.
3. Add a `zip` task to zip the files

Comment: This was useful thanks, I ended up using ```msbuildArgs: '/p:OutputPath="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'``` and then a PublishBuildArtifacts@1 task with ```PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/_PublishedWebsites'```